# How to perform real time regression on sensor data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, real-time

I have made a WSN that takes sensor data with python. I have made a machine learning model that does classification which is not in real-time. Is there any way to perform real-time machine learning prediction on incoming sensor data...

Answer (score 0):

since you're model is already pre-trained, you could probably just use a time iterator and perhaps use transfer learning, followed by evaluating the model. Not sure exactly how to do this but here is some pseudocode:

```
model

For seconds in timeperiod of interest:
   testdata = newdata.test
   train data = newdata.train
   Y = newdata labels

   freeze the first 6 layers of the model
   model.fit(traindata, Y, ...)

   model.evaluate(testdata , Y)
```

Real time machine learning is still a pretty new field. The NSF just had a 10 million dollar grant for research in this field with a deadline that closed last year.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was not using neural networks in this. But thanks for the info, if you have anything about not using neural networks, post it :)